# Interact with custom warehouse api from woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a woocommerce wordpress store.  When an order comes in, I need to transmit the order to our warehouse/fullfillment center using the warehouse's custom api (they wrote it themselves).  In other words, after collecting payment on an order, woocommerce will hit the warehouse api url with a post request and json data about the order.

Can anybody point me to some documentation about how/where to do this in woocommerce?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is look at the "hooks" that are available for Woocommerce. These will allow you to alter the behaviour of Woocommerce at certain points. There are two types of hook: actions and filters. Action hooks allow you to execute custom functions during these 'events' while filter hooks allow you to manipulate data during the 'events'.

Here's an intro from the Woocommerce documentation: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/introduction-to-hooks-actions-and-filters/

Here's the complete Woocommerce reference for Hooks: https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/hook-docs.html